# Magento 1.9.1 Invalid block type

Tags: magento-1.9

```
 <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <category_view>FME_Layerednav_Block_Rewrite_RewriteCatalogCategoryView</category_view>
            </rewrite> 
        </catalog>  



class FME_Layerednav_Block_Rewrite_RewriteCatalogCategoryView extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View
{ 
    public function getProductListHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getProductListHtml();
        if ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getIsAnchor()){
            $html = Mage::helper('layerednav')->wrapProducts($html);
        }
        return $html;
    }   
}
```

Can anyone know what could be wrong ?

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type:
>   FME_Layerednav_Block_Rewrite_RewriteCatalogCategoryView' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trgovine/keramoteka/app/Mage.php:595

Answer (score 2):

Magento knows three reasons for this error:

> 1. if (!$block = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName($block))
> 2. if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract)

and I think both don't fit. So you have to dig.

First check whether the error is thrown here:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:487
```

or here

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:495
```

if you know this, check why the if is failing. I recomment xdebug for this.

- all line numbers are from magento 1.9.1

Comment: error get from file:includes/src/__default.php

if (!$block instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract) {
...
}

Comment: Read https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store